# How To Get paypal transaction Fees?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I integrated PayPal sandbox. I want know how much PayPal deducts as PayPal fees in transaction amount. There is only transaction ID and transaction amount in PayPal return URL. How to get transaction fees for every transaction so that merchant can get exact details of transactions?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the transaction details for each transaction id.  It will return `FEEAMT`

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/gettransactiondetails-api-operation-nvp

The URL for this API is

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/